# when parsing html, check if element is present

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing

Im parsing html from some a page, to get a list of the outgoing, i want to split them in two - the ones with the rel="nofollow" / rel="nofollow me" / rel="me nofollow" element and the ones with with out those expressions.

At the moment im using the code bellow parsed using - [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$html = file_get_html("$url");

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    echo $element->href; // THE LINK
}
```

but im not quite sure how to implement it, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this :

```
$html = file_get_html("$url");

// Creating array for storing links
$arrayLinks = array(
    "nofollow" => array(),
    "others" => array()
);

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {

    // Search for "nofollow" expression with no case-sensitive (i flag)
    if(preg_match('#nofollow#i', $element->rel)) {
        $arrayLinks["nofollow"][] = $element->href;
    }
    else {
        $arrayLinks["others"][] = $element->href;
    }
} 

// Display the array
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayLinks);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a regexp on $element->rel I guess